# react router with flask back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, react-router

I am building a project with react as frontend and flask as backend. I want the application created by 'create-react-app' to use front end routing with 'react-router-dom' package. Relevant code in index.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route component={Notfound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then I want to serve it via flask, so in flask I have following settings and routing rules:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../build/static", template_folder="../build")

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
def serve(path):
    render_template("index.html")
```

Where index.html is built with `npm run build`. When I click on navbar and redirect to `/about`, app returns 404 not found.

Also there's another error in the browser console, which shows: `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Its better to leave routing upto one party - either python (in your case flask) or react. The `catch_all` routing from flask app which is suggested in other comment, should only be used in development purpose, cause normally react apps are just static webapps which can be served with a generic http server (like nginx or apache in production). If you use the flask's `catch_all` alternative in production you will end up wasting resources as the same request could be handled directly from the http server instead of collecting the response from a wsgi server. Its like A, B and C are talking, A wants to call C, he could directly call C, but instead of doing so he asks B to call C, and C replies to B, then B relays the reply to A. Totally unnecessary resource usage. Besides it will get very confusing if you start/try to mix routing of both flask and react. Use one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/full-stack-single-page-application-with-vue-js-and-flask-b1e036315532) for information on how to set up the Flask back end for a single-page application. You need a catch all route to serve up the `index.html` for the About page:

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
  return render_template("index.html")
```

At the tutorial link, you can also find more information on setting up a 404 page on the front end router (the front end described is Vue, but the concept is the same).

Comment: Hi lando! Thanks for your help. I tried this as well, it ends up with front end router not working, `/about` points to home page. I am using flask + uwsgi + nginx to serve the app, is there anything else I should do to make it working?

Comment: Alright I figured it out, the order of <Route /> is wrong, `/` should be after the others

Comment: Oh, strange. In examples I've seen (and my own usage), I have placed the root route `/` before the other pages (e.g., `about`, `contact`, etc.). https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Comment: @lando That's probably because you might have included 'exact' while defining route while defining <Route> for '/'